# US Naval Observatory Sunrise/Sunset Data: Blank Sunrise/Sunset Times?

Tags: light

The US Naval Observatory has a webpage that allows a user to enter a year and a latitude/longitude pair, and then produces a table of sunrise and sunset times for each day during that year at that latitude/longitude pair:

http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/RS_OneYear.php

Sometimes, a blank entry will appear where I would expect to see a time.

For example, in the above webpage, if I scroll down to "Form B - Locations Worldwide," enter the coordinates W074 45, N42 16, leave the "time zone" blank, enter "2015" for the year, and leave all other options at their default settings, **I get a blank entry for May 03.** Can anyone help me to interpret this, or direct me to an appropriate reference?

There is already a symbol for when the sun does not rise and another for when the sun does not set on a particular day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get a blank entry for May 03.

The Sun didn't set on Bovinia, New York on May 03 when time is expressed as Universal Time. Sunsets from May 04 to August 16 occur before sunrise. (Also note that August 16 has two sunsets.)

The solution is simple: Fill in the time zone. Ignoring daylight savings time, time in Bovinia New York is offset by 5 hours from UTC.

Another solution is to use a different website. There are better web services than the simple perl-based script used to generate that table.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot! Can you suggest any such better web services?

Comment: Just a few: http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/ , http://sunrise-sunset.org , http://www.sunrisesunset.com ; there are others. They disagree with one another some extent, but not by very much.